# Why do my includes work with not correct DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, directory

My includes work fine on my vagrant box and don't work in production. Please tell me why?

Example:

```
include 'app\Exceptions\exception_handler.php';
```

It should not work on linux but it works. Why?

**Here is a config on where it works, but should not:**

```
print 'directory separator is ' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "\n"
```

returns

> my directory separator is /

**phpinfo()**

```
PHP Version - 5.6.37-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
System - Linux homestead 4.15.0-22-generic #24-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 16 12:15:17 UTC 2018 x86_64
Server API - Apache 2.0 Handler
Apache Version - Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
```

Is it because I use windows shared folder to keep files that is hosted on Ubuntu vagrant box?

Comment: About your *"It should not work on linux but it works. Why?"* and the line of code you referenced as being `include 'app\Exceptions\exception_handler.php';`. Why would you think that it wouldn't or shouldn't work on a Linux box? It's valid. Ok so it will or might fail if you need a full system path, but that looks good to me. I don't understand your question. I've been reading it a few times and I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: If you're (also) talking about this line `print 'directory separator is ' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "\n"`. That does work with Linux, yes but in Windows it won't show a new line/write a new line with just the `\n`. The missing `\r` isn't a big deal. It fails but not completely. It won't do anything crazy. Edit: The manual doesn't state anything special about Linux/Windows http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php or about mixed environments.

Comment: on Windows directory separator is `\ ` on linux directory separator is `/`. PHP can use `/` even on windows. I'm Using `\ `on Linux Vagrant box where Host is Windows. Source files are sitting on Windows shared folder, that is how Linux is getting this files and process thew with PHP. Please specify what needs explanation.